# use get and make page url

Tags: html

i have this form:

```
<form action = "" method = "get">
<input type = "input" name = "id" value = "3" />
<input type = "input" name = "name" value = "gloris" />
<input type = "submit" class = "button_big" name = "submit" value = "SEND" />
</form>
```

And how make this link (and i must use button):
www.link.com/3/gloris

Comment: You could only do it with JavaScript. *If* this is an option for you, make sure that the form works also with disabled JS.

Comment: If you can do this so that it works with disabled JS then why would you use JS in the first place?

Comment: @controlfreak123: I didn't mean that generating of the URL should work without JS (as I said, that won'T be possible). I said that the *form* should work without JS, implying that the server also accepts the URL in the form of `page?id=3&name=gloris&usbmit=SEND`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Felix says, this requires JavaScript.  It would be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.addEventListener("load", function()
{
  document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function()
  {
    var id = document.getElementById("id").value;
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    window.location = [window.location.replace(/\/$/, ''), id, name].join("/");
  }, false);
}, false); 
</script>

<form action = "" id = "myForm" method = "get">
<input type = "text" name = "id" id = "id"  value = "3" />
<input type = "text" name = "name" id = "name" value = "gloris" />
<input type = "submit" class = "button_big" name = "submit" id = "submit" value = "SEND" />
</form>
```

Note that I added `id` attributes so we can use `document.getElementById`.  Also, there is no input type "input".  It should be `text`, or you can leave it off.  You can add more fields just be adding to the array in the desired order.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="http://www.link.com/3/gloris" method="get">
<input type="submit" value="Go to gloris" />
</form>
```

Comment: I doubt he wants to hard-code the link.  Presumably, those values are just the defaults.

Comment: Its good decision for my, thanks ;). But now url looks like:
http://www.link.com/3/gloris?submit=Go to gloris, how disabled this: "submit=Go to gloris" ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean how do you make a link in the page the form is posted to? Depends on the technology you use. With php it could be

```
<a href="www.link.com/<?=$_GET['id']?>/<?=$_GET['name']?>">Your link name</a>
```

Comment: Now that I read your post... it seems like that's probably what he meant. Shrug.

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is an option for you, have the form action link to code such as this:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['name'])) {
        header('Location: www.link.com/' . $_GET['id'] . '/' . $_GET['name']);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would update your field names. Naming an item "name" is never a great idea. Also, add an id to your form.

```
<form action = "javscript:void();" method = "get"  id = "mainForm">
    <input type = "input" name = "itemId" value = "3" />
    <input type = "input" name = "itemName" value = "gloris" />
    <input type = "submit" class = "button_big" name = "submit" value = "SEND" />
</form>
<button onclick="updateLocation();">Submit</button>
```

Then just make a javascript function like so.

```
<script><!--
     function updateLocation(){
        var formObject=document.getElementById('formObject');
        var i = formObject.itemId.value;
        var n = formObject.itemName.value;
        var url = 'www.link.com/' + i + '/' + n;
        window.location=url;
    }
--></script>
```